# Ignore or override parameters for constructor definition

Tags: typescript, dom

I'm trying to use `new Touch({ identifier: Date.now(), target: elem, clientX: x })` in a unit test, but TypeScript complains with `error 2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`.

The latest version of TS has the correct definition for Touch:

```
declare var Touch: {
    prototype: Touch;
    new(touchInitDict: TouchInit): Touch;
};
```

But our project is still using version 2.9.2, which has an incorrect definition:

```
declare var Touch: {
    prototype: Touch;
    new(): Touch;
};
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typecast the `constructor` to any to work around this problem:

```
new (Touch as any)({ identifier: Date.now(), target: elem, clientX: x })
```

or alias it

```
const Touch2:any = Touch;
new Touch2({ identifier: Date.now(), target: elem, clientX: x })
```

Alternatively, you can add the right typings to that alias (preferred)

```
interface Touch3Interface {
    prototype: Touch;
    new(touchInitDict: TouchInit): Touch;
}
const Touch3:Touch3Interface = Touch as any;
new Touch3({ identifier: Date.now(), target: elem, clientX: x })
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the various options. I had tried `new <any>Touch` but didn't think of `new (Touch as any)`. The other options are also good. Also `<any>Touch` also works if you use parentheses.

Comment: @MichaelBest You're very welcome :). Indeed it works, but the recommended and newer syntax is the "as" syntax. It was introduced because the "<>" syntax clashed with .tsx.